# Can I create an IBM Watson Conversation client application in Javascript without using Node.js?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

Can I create an IBM Watson Conversation client application in Javascript without using Node.js? The ERP software that I'm working in does not allow usage of Node.js. What would a POST request to Watson look like in plain javascript? I see that I need some user/pass credentials, the POST URL. But how do I send the Watson service data? What does the data object need to look like? All the API documentation is using Node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have some way of running javascript on the server you can make a request to IBM Watson with javascript since POST requests to Watson have to be run server side using a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

There is a java sdk for this. As well as Java listed in the API reference.
API ref: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/assistant/api/v1/java.html?java
SDK: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/tree/master/assistant

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can if you follow the CURL documentation here:
https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/assistant/api/v1/curl.html?curl#message

```
curl -X POST -u "{username}":"{password}" --header "Content-Type:application/json" -- 
data "{\"input\": {\"text\": \"Hello\"}}" 
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v1/workspaces/9978a49e-ea89-4493- 
b33d-82298d3db20d/message?version=2018-07-10"
```

In the following request make sure you provide the context JSON that is returned in the response to the previous request
This is an example of the (first) response

```
{
  "intents" : [ {
    "intent" : "hello",
    "confidence" : 0.9755029201507568
  } ],
  "entities" : [ ],
  "input" : {
    "text" : "Hello"
  },
  "output" : {
    "generic" : [ {
      "response_type" : "text",
      "text" : "Hello! What can I do for you?"
    } ],
    "text" : [ "Hello! What can I do for you?" ],
    "nodes_visited" : [ "greeting" ],
    "log_messages" : [ ]
  },
  "context" : {
    "conversation_id" : "a96ec62f-773c-4e84-8be9-f9dbca9f83d0",
    "system" : {
      "dialog_stack" : [ {
        "dialog_node" : "root"
      } ],
      "dialog_turn_counter" : 1,
      "dialog_request_counter" : 1,
      "_node_output_map" : {
        "greeting" : {
          "0" : [ 0, 0 ]
        }
      },
      "branch_exited" : true,
      "branch_exited_reason" : "completed"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How would you do this in the browser without exposing credentials to the end user?

Comment: @MarkMeyer, to hide the credentials you need a proxy/man-in-the-middle. IBM has API Connect, this replaces the credentials with a key.This key is still visible in javascript but you can minimize the 'abuse' by exposing only the message endpoint through this proxy (and not all other operations that modify the assistant). If your ERP system allows for executing serverside code, this could also be the proxy/man-in-the-middle...

Comment: Also, I believe CURL is a PHP only service. The ERP I'm working in only allows plain javascript.

Comment: Ok so I was able to use a proxy server from the ERP and send an HTTP Post request. Now I don't receive a CORS error, but I still receive a 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: So your ERP server allows for serverside javascript or another language to perform a HTTP Post ? And while executing this code the Watson API returns with a 403 ?

Comment: I figured it out. The HTTP Post request was formulated incorrectly. I hadn't included the "/message?version=xxxx" portion of the URL.  The answer is yes. The ERP allows server side javascript and therefore it can call IBM Watson.  Client side javascript cannot.